# Run multiple times, a script that outputs a `csv`

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, csv

I have a simulation setup which generates a `csv` containing the results of the simulation. I want to run this script multiple times and get multiple `csv's` as a result of each simulation.
I tried:

```
import os


sim_no = 1
for i in range(2):
    os.system("python test_sim.py")
    sim_no = sim_no + 1
```

and then importing the sim_no variable to my simulation script but that creates problems.

Comment: I don't understand what u r trying to do you are running same python script 2 times and increasing a value you that are doing nothing with and its non-sense, are you trying to give names to your csv files?

Comment: did you want to do : `os.system(f"python test_sim.py {i}")`?

Comment: @GolgeAdam yes, I import this variable to the other script to change the name of the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your test_sim file instead of trying to execute it

Comment: and run the main function multiple times?

Comment: Exactly. You can import the main function from the file (import function_name from test_sim), and then repeatedly call it (for n in range(10): function_name).